# Clion : Debug into cpp class

Tags: c++, debugging, clion

I want to debug a C++ programm with Clion, my debugger works when I put a breakpoint into the main's class but if I put a breakpoint into a class, gdb doesn't stop the running program when we have to enter into a function of this class from the main's class.

I don't really know why :/
Is it a normal feature ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What do you mean by "main's class" ?

Comment: This is my main's class :

Graph gograph;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    num_of_vertices = gograph.Cliques(argv[1], "clq.temp.txt");
}

This is my class graph.cpp in summary with a graph.h obviously :

int Graph::Cliques(const char *szgraph_filename, const char* szoutput_filename)
{ ... }

I want to put a breakpoint into the class graph but Clion doesn't stop to this breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Does CLion support modes like debug or release? If so, please check in what mode you are trying to debug.

Comment: Yes, I debug in debug mode only, I didn't try the release mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some issue with the bundled GDB CLion is using. Switching to system GDB helped in my case. To do so:

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolchains -> Debugger
and switch "Use bundled GDB" to "Use specified GDB" and supply path: /usr/bin/gdb

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work when you call functions with no arguments.